# Is there a way to mock athena and unit test in python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a huge batch process to process huge amounts of data. I am using athena to perform some parts of processing and I am trying to unit test the functions related tot this. How can I mock athena and unit test the code related to athena

Comment: Since Athena runs on Hive & Presto, you can use a testing framework for them (e.g., tempto)

Comment: @UjjwalBhardwaj i see tempto is available for Java, is there any similar library for python?